# Android OBD-II distance travelled (PID31)

Tags: android, distance, pid, obd-ii

I am trying to read the distance traveled since some codes were cleared from the OBD with an Android application.

I have managed to get the RPM and fuel % to work but the distance traveled is higher than what I would expect.

```
case 49: //PID(31): Distance Travelled(A*256)+B
  Double miles = (((valueA*256)+valueB)*0.62137;
  String displayDistance = String.valueOf("Miles: " + miles);
```

Anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: How much higher? There's not nearly enough information here.

Comment: Sorry I can't get the wifi to work on my PC so doing this from my phone! The car is sitting at roughly 5 thousand miles but the app was reading 7811.24227 miles. Also made it spit out ValueA = 49 and ValueB = 27.

Comment: I'd try a different car, just to be safe. It's not total mileage, but miles since DTC cleared for 0x31. But yes, still seems high.

Comment: Should valueA always be 49? I think that part might be wrong... Because 49 is the decimal of the PID31

Comment: Any chance you have A and B in the wrong order?  Done the other way it gives 4325 miles.  Or drive a km or two and see which number changes.

Comment: Just tried swapping and results were.. A:49, B:28. Miles: 4484.4272. My car has done 4,473 miles.

Comment: It apparently works if valueA is 31 which is the hex of 49 :S

Comment: Well, since B went from 27 to 28 in the course of these comments, it would seem that you have the correct order. The thing I noticed right away is that you have the km/mileage factor in there again. You're coming up with 7811, which x 0.62 = 4,842. That's close. But that wouldn't make sense. I'd get in the car and drive until B flips to 29, reset the trip odo and drive to 37. That should be 5 miles.

Comment: @user3010383, Actually I have a question since I'm working on something similar but I need to calculate distance from point A to point B. Do you know how to clear code (Distance traveled since codes cleared)?

Comment: Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27736828/513413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the code is right but not 100% accurate because I  parsing the bytes into an int and therefore calculation is out by about 7 miles. Will need to find a way to parse as a double. The issue when I am thousands of miles out is a concurrent issue with interleaving of a shared variable.